# Geodesic Formula in terms of First Fundamental Form

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

I may simply be overwhelmed by all the terms in this question, but I am at a point where I feel stuck:

**Given a surface $X(u,v)$ with $u=u(t)$ and $v=v(t)$, and $F=0$, find a formula for the geodesic curvature in terms of the coefficients $E$,$F$,$G$, and the derivatives of $u(t)$ and $v(t)$.**

So it is given that $S=X(u(t),v(t))$ and I know that $k_g = \vert \dot x,\ddot x,e_3 \vert$. The goal is to get $k_g$ in terms of the first fundamental form.

Here's what I have so far:

$$e_3=\frac{X_u \times X_v}{\Vert X_u \times X_v \Vert}$$

Which implies $$e_3=\frac{X_u  \times X_v}{\sqrt{EG}}$$

I know that I am supposed to use the following:

$$X_{uu}=\Gamma{_1}^1{_1}e_1+\Gamma{_1}^2{_1}e_2+Le_3$$
$$X_{uv}=\Gamma{_1}^1{_2}e_1+\Gamma{_1}^2{_2}e_2+Me_3$$
$$X_{vv}=\Gamma{_2}^1{_2}e_1+\Gamma{_2}^2{_2}e_2+Ne_3$$

$$X_{uu}=\frac{GE_u}{2EG}e_1+\frac{-EE_v}{2EG}e_2+Le_3$$
$$X_{uv}=\frac{GE_v}{2EG}e_1+\frac{EG_u}{2EG}e_2+Me_3$$
$$X_{vv}=\frac{-GG_u}{2EG}e_1+\frac{EG_v}{2EG}e_2+Ne_3$$

And it's at this point that I feel like I don't know which direction to go. I've been staring at the problem for over an hour now and I am most confused with trying to rewrite $\dot x$ and $\ddot x$ in terms of $t$...which is how I think I should start.

Thank you for any direction.

Comment: Your formula for $\ddot x$ is not correct. Also, there's confusion with $s$ and $t$. Are you assuming an arclength parametrization or not?

Comment: The formula given for $k_g$ is originally parameterized by arclength, and the goal is to get it into terms only using $t$ and the coefficients of the fundamental form. And if that's not $\ddot x$ then my notes are wrong. I'll have to try and derive it first. Thanks.

Comment: the $\LaTeX$ command for $\times$ is \times